# Running OTEL agent as windows service is not working

Tags: open-telemetry, distributed-tracing, open-telemetry-collector, otel, grafana-tempo

Want to run Otel collecor agent as Windows services. So downloaded latest windows release package and run the following command to create service and start the service.

```
> sc.exe create otelcol displayname= otelcol start= delayed-auto
> binPath=
> "C:\Users\admin\otelcol-contrib_0.94.0_windows_386\otelcol-contrib.exe
> --config C:\Users\admin\Core-Otel.yaml" sc.exe start otelcol
```

but the service is not started and resulted with error on event viewer as

> "The otelcol service terminated with the following error: An exception
> occurred in the service when handling the control request."

Agent version: 0.94.0
OS: Windows 11

Could any one point the right direction to deploy the Otel agent as windows service ?

Comment: Wrong site. For reference: [su]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Windows Desktop, event viewer shows as "Incorrect function." in the general tab. But in the details tab, it is showing as "info service@v0.92.0/service.go:177 Everything is ready. Begin running and processing data" and now able to run as windows service.

Command used:

```
sc.exe create otelcol displayname= otelcol start= delayed-auto
binPath=
\""C:\Users\admin\otelcol-contrib_0.94.0_windows_386\otelcol-contrib.exe\"
 --config \"C:\Users\admin\Core-Otel.yaml\"" 
sc.exe description "Otelcol"
sc.exe start otelcol
```

**Note:** Need to use quotes for path if folder name contains spaces.